# SQL Server language extension performance

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, external-script

A SQL Server Language Extension function is executed in an external process. Does it mean that when such a function is called in a Select clause it creates a new process for every row in the recordset on which it is applied?

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of thinking you can divide the world into performant/non-performant. *If* performance matter to you, set *goals*, write the simplest code that is *correct*, and *measure* the performance. Only the combination where the simple code doesn't match the goals needs to be optimised, and it almost always falls to *specifics* of the situation, not generalised rules. You need to use profiling tools to understand *where* the bottlenecks are before attempting to optimise.

Comment: Thank you Damien, but in this case it seemed to me that it would be hard to meet the goals of any specific situation except the most trivial - having to create thousands or perhaps millions of different processes before getting the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing two different features / technologies.

- **SQLCLR** is the ability to run .NET code (most often C# or VB.NET, but sometimes Visual C++ and occasionally F#, though F# is not officially supported) *within* the SQL Server process. This code can be called as stored procedures, triggers, scalar functions, table-valued functions, aggregate functions, and even user-defined types. This has the ability to execute T-SQL within the calling session, even if there's an active transaction (i.e. true in-process execution).
- **External Scripts (language extensions)** is newer than SQLCLR and is not .NET-specific. Languages that can be used are: R, Python, Java, and most recently C#. This code can *only* be executed via the [sp_execute_external_script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql) stored procedure; there is not option to call these external scripts via a function. Hence, there is no concept of per-row execution. These scripts are executed by a separate service (i.e. external), hence there is no option for in-process T-SQL code execution (meaning: executing T-SQL via an external script will connect as a separate session).

Additional details can be found in my post:
[SQLCLR vs SQL Server 2017, Part 8: Is SQLCLR Deprecated in Favor of Python or R (sp_execute_external_script)?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-8-is-sqlclr-deprecated-in-favor-of-python-or-r-sp_execute_external_script/)

Comment: You're right, sorry, I did confuse these technologies and forgot sp_execute_external_script. But I remember that a stored procedure can be called from within a function as long as it doesn't change state in SQL Server. And even in case the stored procedure does change state, it can be called from SQL CLR by opening a new connection, though it obviously won't be a desired solution.

Comment: @Lorin_F No, you can't exec a stored proc from within a function, else you get the following error: _Msg 557, Level 16, State 2, Line XXXX Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function._ While `sp_execute_external_script` is an extended stored proc, it gets that error if called from within a UDF. Yes, it _could_ be executed per row via SQLCLR, however, external scripts are designed to have a query passed in and operate on the entire set, not row-by-row, so that really begs the question of why go to such lengths and not just use SQLCLR?

Comment: I understand that even if I manage to call the external scripts row by row, the scripts themselves are executed as external sessions. I recall however, that these scripts are executed by the CLR, with data parsed between the CLR and the SQL engine and back. So I wondered whether the CLR part runs in the same process for different script calls.

Comment: SQLCLR presents security issues and as such it demands additional permissions. Besides, it is limited to older versions of the CLR. I just wanted to clarify the issue.

Comment: Suppose you have a query containing a function call. If you prefer to use External Scripts, then you will have to break the query into parts, first the part that is passed in to the External Scripts, and then use the result in some new queries. Finding a way to execute External Scripts row by row may reduce complexity.

Comment: @Lorin_F External scripts should only use CLR if using C#, in which case, I _believe_ that would be a singular process, just like the R / Python / Java runtimes _should_ also be singular for calls from multiple sessions. Yes, unfortunately SQLCLR is stuck on CLR v 4.0 / Framework v 4.8, but that's not really so bad, is it? As far as security risk goes, if you have a link to some actual proof of such I would love to see it, otherwise it's just an unfortunately common misconception (and the poorly worded MS documentation doesn't help).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rutzky for sharing your expertise.

Comment: @Lorin_F Connecting (externally) to new session to call external script (performance hit) to pass results back across two APIs (external back to new session, new session back to calling process) on a row-by-row basis does not in any way strike me as reducing complexity. I'm not trying to be a downer / negative, but as far as I can tell, the proposed setup would be more complex, and require more memory and cpu, than just using SQLCLR (not to mention I don't see any possible way for it to not be noticeably slower given how many extra steps in the process are being added).

Comment: I understand there were reasons for Microsoft to impose restrictions on SQLCLR - anyway, besides security issues there can also be potential memory leaks in such a data heavy domain like SQL Server, with processes potentially running "forever". I understand that the external scripts use some shared memory with SQL Server, to receive data and return results, so they may present a better solution in these respects. However, they seem to be limited in their abilities, as I mentioned above, and I wished to check possible workouts. Thanks.

Comment: @Lorin_F Memory leaks are possible, but not necessarily the case. Is this something you've seen in testing? And again about supposed security "issues", if you know of something specific then please share the link, else please stop spreading that misinformation. If you are referring to the MS doc regarding "clr strict security" and newer .NET no longer using CAS, then that doc is almost certainly misleading and inaccurate (and as far as I know has never been proven). All of that being said, I still recommend testing as I haven't and my assessment _could_ be wrong. Good luck with your project 